# Type Error while using variables

Tags: python

So i have this line of code:

```
fc = round((1+5*100)/100, 3) if fc_no_rocks == None else round(fc_no_rocks/100, 3)
```

that takes in a variable, whose type should be float. When I test the variable type using type(), it returns:

```
>>>type(fc_no_rocks)
<type 'float'>
```

but i keep getting an error that says "unsupported operand types for /: str and int.

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the error is coming from this line?

Comment: What do you mean by self-contained example; and yes.

Comment: Tried your code and works as expected: http://pastie.org/8153588. What's between your variable initialisation and when you actually use it in that expression?

Comment: The code works fine for e.g., `fc_no_rocks = 1.1`. So the error is somewhere else ;-)

Comment: Unrelated, but worth mentioning: You don't test against the `None` singleton using `==` but using `is`.

Comment: If you look at the error message, it will tell you the line number of the file that the error occurs.

Comment: For the record, by "self-contained example" he meant "an example we can copy and paste into a fresh interpreter and see the problem".  See [this useful reference](http://sscce.org) for more on what a "short self-contained correct example" is and why it matters.

Comment: Maybe you have a local variable shadowing a global. Is this code inside a function? And is `fc_no_rocks` a global variable?

Comment: Are you doing the `type(fc_no_rocks)` test _just before_ the problematic line, or anywhere else?

Comment: i'm doing it before and after, and when declared

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Dylansq, the only way to get through this is if you post your relevant code (from where you create fc_no_rocks to that fc=blabla call)

Comment: ok give me one second. sorry i'm trying go through everything at the same time

Comment: @Dylansq You accepted my answer, but I'm curious, what exactly about it got it working for you? Did you discover your bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a for loop that had changed the variables so the fc_no_rocks was set to None. This made the logic when setting the fc variable switch to the left, where one of the variables i had replaces was also a string. sorry for the mixup

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, `fc_no_rocks` is a string in your case. That bug is on you. Better to check for several cases:

1. `fc_no_rocks` is a number
2. `fc_no_rocks` is a string indicating a number
3. `fc_no_rocks` is neither of the above

You check to make sure that `fc_no_rocks` isn't `None`, but it could be *anything*. So it's better to check more exclusively at first, and then let your `else` case be the catch-all, i.e. neither/none of the above.

In one big mess of a ternary chain, it's this:

```
fc = round(float(fc_no_rocks)/100.0, 3) if isinstance(fc_no_rocks, str) and unicode(fc_no_rocks.replace('.','',1)).isnumeric() else round(fc_no_rocks/100.0, 3) if isinstance(fc_no_rocks, float) or isinstance(fc_no_rocks, int) else round((1+5*100)/100.0, 3)
```

Better to write it out in multiple lines, imo, but one-liners are such fun to write. It's like putting a bucket of water on top of a door that you know someone else is going to walk through. It sucks to be the person maintaining your code...! (By the way, make sure that you quit your job after writing this sort of stuff so that you don't have to be the one maintaining it.)

Anyway, output:

```
>>> fc_no_rocks = "2.3"
>>> fc = ...
>>> fc
0.023
>>> fc_no_rocks = "foobar"
>>> fc = ...
>>> fc
5.01
>>> fc_no_rocks = 1.3
>>> fc = ...
>>> fc
0.013
>>> fc_no_rocks = 6340
>>> fc = ...
>>> fc
63.4
```

If you want to debug right in the middle of that statement, I have good news:

```
>>> import sys
>>> fc_no_rocks = "foobar"
>>> fc = round(float(fc_no_rocks)/100.0, 3) if sys.stdout.write(str(type(fc_no_rocks))+"\n") or isinstance(fc_no_rocks, str) and unicode(fc_no_rocks.replace('.','',1)).isnumeric() else round(fc_no_rocks/100.0, 3) if isinstance(fc_no_rocks, float) or isinstance(fc_no_rocks, int) else round((1+5*100)/100.0, 3)
<type 'str'>
>>> fc
5.01
```

You can abuse the boolean `or` operator's behavior and the fact that the `write()` method always returns `None`! Hooray! You can also write `repr(fc_no_rocks)` instead if you want to see its representation - useful for getting both the contents of a string and an indication that yes, it is a string.

*Edit: I'm running Python 2.7.2, so I had to add the decimal points to divide correctly. Woops!*

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make sure `fc_no_rocks` is a float?

```
fc = round((1+5*100)/100, 3) if fc_no_rocks == None else round(float(fc_no_rocks)/100, 3)
```

Comment: If his fc_no_rocks holds a non-numeric value, this won't do any good

Comment: but the error says otherwise :) And, with a more critic eye, all I'm saying is don't force typecasts unless you really know what's going on .

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo: Hhm...good points. However, if that is the case, then he has something _fundamentally_ wrong with his script.  He says it _should_ be a float, but the error says it is a string.  This means that it is most likely something like `'1.0'`, which `float` will fix.  If it isn't--and is instead something like `'string'`--then he has a major problem that has nothing to do with the line of code he gave.

Comment: It's still something you want to avoid, it may result in shadowing that "fundamentally wrong" bit in your script.

Comment: You will have to check if it is an instance of a string or else you could end up trying to cast `True` to a float as well. And then you have to check if it's numeric, too.

Comment: @2rs2ts: I understand that.  My philosophy is this: `fc_no_rocks` _should_ be a float.  If it isn't a float, then the next most likely thing that it is is something like this: `'1.0'`, which `float` will fix.  However, if it is neither (and is a bool, or a list, or whatever), then the line of code he gave is not the problem.  Instead, he has something seriously wrong in another part of his script.  Hence, he should go and fix the part of his script that defines `fc_no_rocks` so that it makes it a float or something like `"1.0"`.  See where I'm going?

Comment: @iCodez Yes, of course. It would be better to use `try`/`except` anyway. I assumed you knew that, I just wanted to comment to make sure that anyone (e.g. OP) reading would get that note.

Answer (score 0):

There is one other thing.
`round((1+5*100)/100, 3)` there is nothing to round, because the numeric literals are all integers and the result of this integer equation `(1+5*100)/100` which includes a division  is **5**, not **5.01** as you would expect. To repair it you have to use all decimal literals in every of your decimal calculations:

```
round((1.0+5.0*100.0)/100.0, 3)
```

EDIT: The repaired statement would result in 5.01, so you should be careful in other parts of your code.

Comment: Unless this is python3, in which case floats are returned on division

Comment: "i removed other int variables to clear it up a little;" 

Uhu... could it be possible that the problem is with these other (supposed) "int" variable ? Given the error message, the answer is very very certainly "yes".

Comment: I think he meant "value" not variable

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo: I think he really means "variable" and just replaced these other variables with int litterals in the snippet he posted.

Comment: The result is not `5.0`, it is in fact `5.01`... at least on my machine. Running 2.7.2.